# Furnace with no “C” connection

Tags: hvac, thermostat, furnace, thermostat-c-wire

[image: 2, 24 volt wires coming from the condenser to the the furnace with no “C” connection]I have a mobile home furnace. This furnace only has a 4 wire connection terminal, G,W,R,Y. I also have a condensing unit outside with the 24 volt 2 wires coming to the furnace. I know I connect one to Y, but I don’t know what to connect the other wire to? Yes my furnace is AC ready.[image][image]

Comment: Can you post photos of the inside of the furnace's wiring compartment? What make and model is said furnace, for that matter?

Comment: 2.5 ton 14 SEER 80% AFUE 56,000 BTU Revolv AccuCharge Mobile Home Air Conditioner and Gas Furnace System. I bought it from HVAC.com

Answer (score 1):

### It's the grey wire in the thermostat wire bundle

According to the wiring diagram posted for your furnace, the C wire should be the *grey* wire in the thermostat wiring area of your furnace.  So, you should just be able to connect to that.